# WinUsb_ReadPipe Return False and Timeout

Tags: c#, winusb

I have to convert an application from C++(a working one) to C#. However, in the newly C# codes, I fail to read the data using WinUsb_ReadPipe, despite successfully in other operation such WinUsb_GetDescriptor, WinUsb_QueryDeviceInformation, WinUsb_Initialize, WinUsb_WritePipe.

In the WinUsb_SetPipePolicy (Read) I have set,

- Raw_IO = true
- AUTO_CLEAR_STALL = True
- TRANSFER_TIMEOUT = 1000 //1s

While for the WinUsb_SetPipePolicy (Write) I only set the TRANSFER_TIMEOUT = 1000.

When I execute the WinUsb_ReadPipe, the transaction FAIL and the Last error is 121 (ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT).

This is the codes I used to read the pipe.

```
        if (!(InTEGRAusbHandle.IsInvalid)) 
        {
            do
            {
                bytesReaded = nBytesToRead;

                try
                {
                    isSuccess = NativeMethods.WinUsb_ReadPipe(
                                              InTEGRAusbHandle,
                                              InTEGRA_BULK_IN.PipeId, //PipeId = 131
                                              bRxBuffer, //bRxBuffer[65536]
                                              nBytesToRead, //64
                                              ref bytesReaded,
                                              IntPtr.Zero);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    isSuccess = false;
                    return false;
                    throw;
                }
                if (!isSuccess)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()); 
                }

                timeoutCounter++;
            } while ((isSuccess == false) && (timeoutCounter <= 1));}
```

Once The code is executed, I get

- isSuccess = FALSE
- bytesReaded = 0

Comment: Have you checked content of exception `ex`?

Comment: There is no content of exception ex, because there is no error while executing the try..catch code.. TQ

Comment: I have solved the problems. It was about the error checking

Comment: Please include your solution as an answer, for reference.

Comment: Ok.. I upload it tonight.